# How to use an endpoint as a function inside another function using express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I want to get the shop if shop does not exist then call `app.post()` to add a new shop.

My `app.post()` it creates the shop successfully:

```
app.post('/shops/addShop', (req, res) => {
      const shop = {
        id: 'shop' + (shops.length + 1),
        name: req.body.name,
        departmentList: [
        {
          id: 'd1',
          name: "department 1"
        },
        {
          id: 'd2',
          name: "department 2"
        },
        {
          id: 'd3',
          name: "department 3"
        }
        ]
      };
   
      shops.push(shop);
      res.send(shop);
});
```

How to implement `getShop()` by Id if exist otherwise create it by using `app.post()`:

```
app.get('/shops/:id', (req, res) => {
   // how to code here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `app.post()` directly, that's an API controller, instead you want to have a separate function that performs this logic.

```
app.post('/shops', (req, res) => {
  res.send(createNewShop());
});

app.get('/shops/:id', (req, res) => {
  const shopExists = findShop(req.params.id);

  if (!shopExists) {
    return res.send(createNewShop());
  } else {
    // do something with your shop
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I am facing error of *req is not defined* when making createNewShop() with req param.

Comment: You have to provide the example of your code but I'll assume you're attempting to use `req.something` within that function ? If that is the case you need to call it as `createNewShop(req)` instead of `createNewShop()`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I am done with it Thanks :)

Comment: @ftslaptoppc please mark the answer with the green checkmark and upvote if it helped